# How to save pointer in JavaScript and retrieve further

Tags: c, node.js, electron, ffi, ref

I am using a `dll` at the server side for some computation . I am calling the `dll` from `nodeJS` using `ffi` module , so somewhere in the middle i need to save the address of the `C pointer` and used it further but I don't know how to save it so that i can pass it after some time to `dll` for executing operation on the same address.

does anyone have idea how to do this.

Comment: I am not sure trying to send an address to node is a good idea.

Comment: @nm_tp so where to store the handle i.e. address

Comment: if you are not able to answer the question then please don't give it negative rating. and if you give it negative rating then give the proper reason why you give negative rating to this question.

Comment: You have been given given downvotes because your question provides very little information. You also have no [Minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Regarding your question in the comments, I answered but it was deleted for some reason. All in all, try to store pointers (addresses) in the dll itself.

Comment: @nm_tp so this reason is not enough for downvotes and i think you don't have any experience on working of `electronJS` 'FFI module'   if you have then you don't talk like this so  better to read this topic first and then try to answer such kind of question . Good Luck

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't downvote. If I could, I most definitely would. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot and trying different-2 scenarios finally i found a solution that how to store the address and retrieve in future for further operations :-

(Note:- here i am using [ref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ref), [ffi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffi) modules)
so for storing pointer , create a buffer that can hold pointer type like below

```
     const ref = require('ref');        
     const  ffi = require('ffi');

     var buf = ref.alloc('pointer');
     ref.writePointer(buf, 0, pointer);  // pointer or memory address
```

so here you store the memory address in buffer and where you want to use you can retrieve it from buffer like below:-

```
     memory_pointer = ref.readPointer(buf,0);   // buf is buffer which we created above, 0 for offset
```

so now you get the `memory_pointer` so you can pass it to your function call using `ffi` module.

Comment: Why couldn't you just store the `pointer` variable (in block 1) directly?